# Can't make content resistance work in a table view cell

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a UITableViewController that has a static field that displays a location.
The style this static field is "right detail".
The left side of the cell shows the city chosen by the user and the right side has an disclosure indicator with the label "Item Location".

When the user first navigates to this controller the left label is set to "No location" and everything looks fine, like this: (I can't post images since I don't have the rep) 
"No location          Item Location >"

The problem is that if I set a long city name (such as "Rancho Santa Margarita, California) the "Item Location" label shrinks and becomes filled with ellipsis (...) 
"Rancho Santa Margarita, California  It... >"

What I want to happen is that when the user picks a long city name then the city label will take as much space as it can without causing the "Item Location" label to shrink.
So basically it will look something like this: 
"Rancho Santa Margarita, ... Item Location >"

Using the interface builder I tried setting both the Horizontal Content Hugging priority and Compression Resistance Priority of the right detail label (Item Location) to 1000 and I even set Horizontal Content Hugging priority and Compression Resistance priority of the city label to 1, but this doesn't seem to work. (it still looks like the second screenshot).

One more thing, when the user selects a new location I use the following method to update the location text:

```
- (void)setLocationText:(NSString *)text {
    self.locationField.textLabel.text = text;
    [self.locationField setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Where locationField is an outlet of the location UITableViewCell.
Without the code to `setNeedsLayout` the city text label doesn't grow to fit the city name, so that's the reason why I used this.

I'm using XCode 4.6 and targeting iOS 6.1

Do you guys know what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance,
Ido

Answer (score 0):

Another option to using autolayout, is to subclass `UITableViewCell` with two label outlets and implement `layoutSubviews`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGSize rightLabelSize = [self.rightLabel sizeThatFits:self.contentView.frame.size];

    CGRect rightLabelFrame = CGRectZero;
    rightLabelFrame.origin.x = self.contentView.frame.size.width - rightLabelSize.width;
    rightLabelFrame.size = rightLabelSize;
    self.rightLabel.frame = rightLabelFrame;

    CGRect leftLabelFrame = CGRectZero;
    leftLabelFrame.size.width = self.contentView.frame.size.width - rightLabelSize.width;
    self.leftLabel.frame = rightLabelFrame;
}
```

Note that this does not add padding or really care much about the height of the labels, so you would need to modify to account for those things.

If you don't like subclassing, then you could construct and size the labels before you return the cells in your controllers `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` protocol method.